# Chef deployment using Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra

I would like to create a declarative Jenkins pipeline setup for the continues integration and Deployment, My only confusion was how Jenkins and chef are going to communicate in this process, after the continue integration, I want the chef to take over and install the Jar or Zip packages and deploy them on the several nodes from Jfrog Repo. Here maven is my build tool. In Jenkins pipeline I can setup until the build is done , is there any thing that I can do in the Post section of the pipeline for the chef communication for deployment or it has to be done. Please share some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting workstation in one of the jenkins node.
Check out the below image for the same, instead of Ansible use Chef. I suppose this might work, haven't use chef recently.
Link: https://thenucleargeeks.com/2020/06/07/jenkins-openshift-pipeline/
[image]

Comment: Hi Aditya, Thanks for sharing the above details.This is really helps. However in the above images I see Jenkins connect SLAVE2 Ansible (i.e., in this case it's Chef) and Nexus. But my pipeline will be GIT<->Jenkins<->Nexus<->Chef->different Environments such as Dev, QA, UAT and Prod to deploy the codes.... Also if you can specify or share the chef plugin name that need to be installed on Jenkins to connect Chef WS will be really helpful.

Comment: Along with if you can share connecting chef from Declarative Pipeline code[sample code], copy from JFrog Artifactory to Chef Client or Workstation, etc.,will be very helpful....